# Floating header below UINavigationBar as a subview - receive touches?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a floating `UIView` header below a `UINavigationBar`. I have inserted it as a subview at index 0, so I can animate it away and in according to contentOffset of a `UITableView`.

However, because it's beyond the bounds of the `UINavigationBar` I cannot receive touch events in this view after adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it. All touch events go to the `UITableView` below it.

Any ideas if it's possible to have a subview outside of the bounds of the navigation bar and receive touch events for it?

I did this because adding it as a subview of a `UITableView`, I'd have to set the Y origin based on the contentOffset while scrolling and this also makes animations very difficult since the Y origin changes during scroll, so I can't know where to animate it to.

It's similar to the header in the Facebook app with "Status", "Photo" and "Check In" buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom UINavigationBar and reimplement `pointInside:withEvent:` to extend touchable area of navigation bar (add your view area):

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect extendedRect = self.frame;
    extendedRect.size.height += MENU_HEADER_HEIGHT - self.frame.origin.y;
    BOOL pointInside = NO;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(extendedRect, point)) {
        pointInside = YES;
    }
    return pointInside;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer. Here is what I did.

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if(self.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)){
            self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }else{
            self.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }

        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        var extendedRect:CGRect = self.frame
        extendedRect.size.height += 100.0 - self.frame.origin.y
        var pointInside:Bool = false

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(extendedRect, point)){
            pointInside = true
        }
        return pointInside
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't receive touch events outside the bounds of a view. So, I see a couple options:

First, you could go with the option of adding it as a subview to the `UITableView`, as you said, then adjusting its Y origin based on the tableview's contentOffset. When you want to animate it, instead of animating it to a specific y position you could do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^{
                     _myHeaderView.frame = CGRectOffset(_myHeaderView.frame, 0.0, -_myHeaderView.frame.size.height);
                 }];
```

Another option I could see is adding the header view on top of everything, but with its origin sitting just below the `UINavigationBar`. Then when you animate it you could just move it to be below the `UINavigationBar` (or even actually pass it to the `UINavigationBar`) and animate after that so that it slides up underneath.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of the latter option as the last option. Again, the offset changes with scrolling, so imagine you scroll fast which means you're animating it to a position that is no longer valid. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Oh are you saying that you want to animate it while scrolling? Or just pin it in place while scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 solution:

```
class TappableNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = self.point(inside: point, with: event)
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        var extendedRect = frame
        extendedRect.size.height += 300.0 - frame.origin.y
        return extendedRect.contains(point)
    }
}
```